# Which side of a silver atom is "north" and which is "south"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons, quantum-spin, atoms

From what little I've learned about quantum mechanics, I understand that atoms with electrons whose spins don't cancel each other out act like tiny magnets. I assume this means these atoms, like silver atoms, have a north and south pole. But if electrons are described as a giant cloud that surrounds the nucleus, then how do you know which way the particle is "pointing"? Or is spin not a physical direction? Please help me understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atoms with one unpaired electron, like silver, do indeed act like tiny bar magnets; however, if the atom is in isolation, the direction of north and south is not well defined until you measure it.

Specifically, an atom with one unpaired electron can react in one of two ways to an applied magnetic field gradient: it can either move in the direction of the gradient (we'll call this "spin-up") or against the gradient (we'll call this "spin-down"). No matter which direction your applied field gradient points, you will always measure the atom's spin as either up or down - nothing in between. (This is why we say spin is *quantized* - measurements of it only take on a finite number of values).

Because of this, the position of north and south on the atom depend on the direction in which we measure. This may seem odd, but that's because the spin of an atom is not like a typical magnetic moment, which is a vector. Instead, it exists as a quantum state, which is a fundamentally different object. In the case of a silver atom (or, in general, a spin-1/2 particle), the spin of an object is a pair of two complex numbers, both of which lie on the unit circle in the complex plane. These two complex numbers are related to the relative probabilities of detecting the atom in the spin-up and spin-down configurations, respectively, relative to some arbitrarily chosen (fixed) direction. If both numbers are nonzero, we say the object is in a *superposition* of spin states in a certain direction. If one of them is zero, we say the object is in a *pure* spin state in that direction.

Specifying these two complex numbers actually determines the relative probabilities of measuring spin-up or spin-down in *any* arbitrary direction. In order to determine the probabilities when measuring in a different direction than the one you originally specified, all you have to do is transform the two complex numbers in a particular way.

So, long story short:

- An atom's north and south poles will only ever be measured to be along the direction you're measuring them in, and
- Unless the atom is in a pure spin state in the direction you're measuring, you will always have some probability of measuring its north pole pointing in one direction, and some probability of measuring its north pole pointing in the other direction.